# TableViewController within a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UIViewController (StoreViewController), and in it's .xib is a UITableView to the left, and a standard UIView to the right. I have created a UITableViewController called StoreTableController and want to somehow make it the the controller of the table view within the StoreView.xib.

Unfortunately, I need to keep the File Owner of the nib file as StoreViewController. I have a delegate within the StoreTableController which has been set as the StoreViewController (this is for calling certain methods), and within the StoreViewController I have an instance of the StoreTableController.

So far I have tried keeping an outlet of the UITableView within StoreViewController and then doing this:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.tableController];

[self.tableController setTableView:self.table];

[self.table setDataSource:self.tableController];
[self.table setDelegate:self.tableController];
```

Where self.table is the outlet, and self.tableController is the instance of the StoreTableController.

However, I do not fully understand how to use UIViewController containment, so this is obviously incorrect.

I have tried variations of this as well, but really don't know what to do.

I have avoided using a UISplitViewController here because not only is the left view larger than the right, but also there are various things I plan to do which mean this must be done in a single .xib file if possible.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is your issue? are you not getting any delegate calls on StoreTableController for tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put a regular `UIView` instead of a UIScrollView in your *.xib*. Connect it with an `IBOutlet` called "tableContentView".

Then, create a new instance of `UITableViewController` (or your custom class, derived from `UITableViewController`) in your code, and add its `UIView` to the tableContentView like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //  Add tableView
    UITableViewController *someTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    someTableViewController.view.frame = self.tableContentView.bounds;
    someTableViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.tableContentView addSubview:someTableViewController.view];        
}
```